# Should I use a message queue to guarantee a windows service only operates on one record at time?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

Just came across a article talking about message queuing. I have a service that runs a process every 1 seconds. The process changes a static bool called 'ProcessLock' to true. The process then checks to see if this variable is true before it executes like this:

```
if (!ProcessLock)
{
    ProcessLock= true;
    //dostuff
}
```

However if this process was to loop round again and enter the bracket just after another thread has entered after the bracket but before it has changed the bool to true then we would get a problem because the code inside would start to operate twice on the same records. What is this condition called? Im sure its got a multithreading term?

Anyway the real point is can I use MSMQ to get round this problem? Whats the process in general?

Comment: It's a 'race' condition.

Comment: You could still run into a race condition with the snippet of code shown above (though not likely). A better fix to the snippet is to use `lock(process) { /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messaging is usually used to ensure reliable delivery and to relax temporal coupling between services.

As I understand your service is operating on the same data each time it is executed. In that case, message queue wouldn't help you much; after all, there can be multiple messages being processed in parallel. You could configure your message handling to run on a single thread (handle one message at a time), but simple lock could solve this problem more easily.

On the other hand, if you could create *work items* for your service to process, some sort of queue would be beneficial. It can be simple home grown `Queue<WorkItem>`, with no complicated messaging infrastructure if you don't care about reliability and don't need inter-process communication.